# get the data from SharePoint list in between dates using linq

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list, linq

i getting the date range from sql, i am passing the date range in linq query as below to display employee time-offs in that pay-period.

```
 var query = from l in leaves
                        where (l.Company == Convert.ToString(500)&&(l.StartDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(PayCheckDates[0].ToString()).Date) && (l.StartDate <= Convert.ToDateTime(PayCheckDates[1].ToString()).Date))
                        select new 
                        {
                            l.Title,
                            l.RequesterImnName,
                            l.ManagerImnName,
                            l.StartDate,
                            l.EndDate,
                            l.TotalHours,
                            l.VacationType

                        };
```

i am able to get the results if the start-date begins in that pay-period.
lets say the PayCheckDates[0] is **2018-05-28** and PayCheckDates[1] is **2018-06-10** is person took time off from **2018-05-25 to 2018-06-05**. it is not showing in that result, because the start date of that timeoff is before PayCheckDates0, if an employee took the time off before current payperiod to next payperiod, i want to show that time off in both current and next period views

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @Shridhar J Joshi elaborated the question

Answer (score 0):

with this you can get the data in between dates in all cases

```
var query = from l in leaves
                            where (l.Company == Convert.ToString(500) && ((l.StartDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(PayCheckDates[0].ToString()).Date) && (l.StartDate <= Convert.ToDateTime(PayCheckDates[1].ToString()).Date))
                            || ((l.EndDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(PayCheckDates[0].ToString()).Date) && (l.EndDate <= Convert.ToDateTime(PayCheckDates[1].ToString()).Date)))
                            select new
                            {
                                l.Title,
                                l.RequesterImnName,
                                l.ManagerImnName,
                                l.StartDate,
                                l.EndDate,
                                l.TotalHours,
                                l.VacationType

                            };
```